# How to execute an app without elevation?

Tags: qt, uac, shellexecute

I want to invoke an updater to check for updates (not to actually do the update but only check if there is any). I would like to do this in the background and silently. If there is an update, I would ask the user for elevated permissions and run the updater with that. The checking involves reading a file in the application's directory and comparing the version found in it with the one on a website.

How can I run it without elevation for checking only? `QProcess::start()` fails because it needs elevated permission and `ShellExecute` only works if I add the "runas" verb for the same reason (which I only want if there would be actually writing in that directory i.e. I want to perform an update). I'm guessing I need to add some sort of manifest but I don't know its contents.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So it turns out that I had another bug that caused the non-elevated running branch to run in all cases. The model I described in the post works. To avoid Windows infering the need for elevated permissions, you need to add a manifest resource. (for example, if the name of your application exe contains the word "updater" it will be triggered)

The contents of the manifest are the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

Compiling it to your .exe depends on your compiler and environment, so I'm only showing mine: Qt Creator and mingw-gcc:

Create an rc file for the resources with the following content:

```
1 24 DISCARDABLE manifest.xml
```

Add this rc file to your .pro like this:

```
win32:RC_FILE = resources.rc
```

After this, ShellExecute without the verb paramter will run without elevation, and using "runas" will run it with elevation.

Answer (score 4):

Elevation prompt appears when your application requests it, for some reason. You can control it with the application manifest. See [*Create and Embed an Application Manifest (UAC)*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) article for details on how to add the manifest.

I would suggest you the following:

1. Separate your *Updater* and *Update Checker*, so that they're in different .EXE files.
2. UpdateChecker.exe requires no administrator privileges, and thus  `requestedExecutionLevel` element of the manifest has `asInvoker` level.
3. Updater.exe requires administrator privileges because it writes updated application file into Program Files. Therefore `requestedExecutionLevel` element of its manifest has `requireAdministrator` level.

In your program you can launch UpdateChecker.exe whatever way you like. To start Updater.exe you will have to use `ShellExecute`; if the application has the manifest (and I strongly recommend embedding manifest) it will show UAC prompt for elevation if the application wants administrator privileges. There's no need to use `runas` verb.

Alternatively you can check whether update is available or not from your main application. And launch the Updater.exe only when there's a new version on the server.

---

Another option would be to make Updater.exe both check for update and apply it if there's one, just like you do it now. In this case Updater.exe should have `asInvoker` level in its manifest. When it starts, *without parameters*, it checks whether there's a new version on the server. If it finds newer version, it *re-launches itself* with administrator privileges and passes a command-line parameter, for example `/doUpdate`, which instructs it do perform the actual update.

In order to re-launch itself elevated, it has to use `ShellExecute` function and `runas` verb, because `ShellExecute` will be unable to detect automatically your Updater.exe now requires administrative privileges.

Keep in mind that the meaning of `runas` verb differs between Windows XP and Windows Vista/7, so you should handle this situation if you want to support previous versions of Windows. The first approach I described will work on Windows XP without additional handling.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! I will investigate the problem further on Monday and might go with the splitting solution. I checked the manifest in wyUpdate (a commercial updater) that does both the checking and updating and it is set to "asInvoker" permission level which is the lowest possible. I might have overlooked something, it might work as I originally planned. I'll let you know.

Comment: I did, if you are interested, check out my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use one of these scenarios:

- put that file in user's profile instead of application's path
- copy content of that file to user's profile in case of it's in read only mode then run   `QProcess::start()`
- include that file inside .qrc file then extract it to user's profile in case of failing of read or run `QProcess::start()`